# automate elastic enterprise with ansible playbook

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, automation, ansible

I would really like someone's help on this platform to help me with this.

**Task:**
I want to deploy with ansible playbooks elastic search deployment template, instead of creating it manually in the console, I would love to automate the flow.

Here is the command to execute this via cli, but what would that look like if I were to translate this below command into an ansible playbook?

`curl -k -X POST -H "Authorization: ApiKey $ECE_API_KEY" https://$COORDINATOR_HOST:12443/api/v1/deployments -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '`

I have tried this but no success:

```
- hosts: primary
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Create Deployment
      uri:
        url: "https://eastus2.azure.elastic-dev.xxx.com/deployments/create"
        method: POST
        user: admin
        password: password
        body: "{{ lookup('file','deployments.json') }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 200
        body_format: json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the answer just in case someone ever stumbled into this situation:

```
---
- hosts: primary
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Create Deployment
      uri:
        url: "{{ url_deploy }}"
        method: POST
        body: "{{ lookup('file','deployments.json') }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 201
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "ApiKey {{ ECE_API_KEY }}"
```